# creating a movie database

Tags: java, android

Hi is there anyway I can incorporate an entire movie database to an android application ? I am using java to code and I cannot figure out whether to use sql lite. But even if that is the case I don't know how to exactly I am supposed to code all that considering I need to classify the movies according to genres, year, duration, a trailer and plot.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some existing movie database online that allow requesting their data.

Like

```
 http://www.omdbapi.com/ 
 https://www.themoviedb.org/
 http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/
```

There are lot of them on the internet. I'm related with none.

Send your request, parse the response and show info to your users. You don't have to store the data in the phone.

This is an example of requesting "jaws" in the first site

> {"Title":"Jaws","Year":"1975","Rated":"PG","Released":"20 Jun
>   1975","Runtime":"124 min","Genre":"Adventure, Drama,
>   Thriller","Director":"Steven Spielberg","Writer":"Peter Benchley
>   (screenplay), Carl Gottlieb (screenplay), Peter Benchley (based on the
>   novel by)","Actors":"Roy Scheider, Robert Shaw, Richard Dreyfuss,
>   Lorraine Gary","Plot":"When a gigantic great white shark begins to
>   menace the small island community of Amity, a police chief, a marine
>   scientist and a grizzled fisherman set out to stop
>   it.","Language":"English","Country":"USA","Awards":"Won 3 Oscars.
>   Another 10 wins & 16
>   nominations.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNDcxODkyMjY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTk5NTc5MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"79","imdbRating":"8.1","imdbVotes":"399,080","imdbID":"tt0073195","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}